# Do you have to permanently sacrifice turns/rebukes for more daily Devotion Feat uses?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, cleric

I've been reading Complete Champion and I came across a conflict the in text that I need resolved.

On page 52, in the Domain Feats section, the text reads:

> If you have the ability to turn or rebuke undead, you can gain additional daily uses of a domain feat’s benefit by permanently sacrificing daily uses of that ability.

But under the specific feat it uses the word "expend", like you're just using a use/day of Turn Undead.

For example Travel Devotion uses the text:

> Special: If you have the ability to turn or rebuke undead you gain one additional daily use of this feat for each two daily turn or rebuke uses you expend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it’s a daily thing. Each day, you may expend a use of Turn Undead (as if you’d actually used it) to power a [Divine] or [Domain] feat, gaining the benefit of the feat instead of performing a Turn Undead action. When your spells refresh, so do your uses of Turn Undead.

Which is part of what makes Cleric such a great dip: anyone with a Charisma of at least 12 gets three minutes worth of Swift-action movement per day. *On top* of some minor spells, decent stats, and the opportunity to get another couple of feats from other Domains/Devotions (Cloistered Cleric can grab Knowledge Devotion).